Modify an element in selenium
I'm not familiar with HTML but I'd like to change a value into a matrix using selenium in python.
The html code of the page is the following:
<div role="grid" class="table-data" style="overflow: auto; height: 872px; width: 1008px;"><div><div role="rowgroup" class="grid-header" style="z-index: 1; width: 1563px;"><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="dl0n"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="dl0n" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="">key</div><div role="gridcell">hmi_id</div></div></div><div role="rowgroup" class="grid-content" style="width: 1563px;"><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="rek0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="rek0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="21m6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="21m6" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="kowy"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="kowy" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="1bmd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="1bmd" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="oo5o"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="oo5o" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div><div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="wcb0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="wcb0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div></div></div></div>

using chrome with the inspection I've seen that the value I want to modify is the third gridcell and I'd like to insert/replace the existing value with another one (e.g. 100).
I've so tried to do this using:
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="madpenguin"]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = '100'", element)

but I'm getting the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="madpenguin"]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]"}

as you can see there are 3 columns and several rows. I'm interested in modify the 3 column in each row.

this is the html code of each row:
<div role="row" class=""><div role="gridcell" class="checkbox"><div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"><div role="img" class="control-element" aria-labelledby="rek0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M19.5 4.4L8.8 20.5 4.5 14l1-0.9 3.3 5L18.5 3.5 19.5 4.4z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" id="rek0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div><div role="gridcell" class="editable"><input autocomplete="off"></div></div>


I did not find id=madpenguin in the HTML shared in the question. Based on shared HTML, try the below XPath expression:
(//div[@class='grid-content']//input)[5]

Explanation: (//div[@class='grid-content']//input)[5] selects the fifth <input> element that is a descendant of a <div> element with the class attribute set to grid-content in the HTML document. If you want the sixth element, just change to [6], for seventh [7] and so on.
Example code:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='grid-content']//input)[5]").send_keys("100")


ciao thanks for the support. I've understood you've made a search through the class but this modify the first column (4th element/row) of the matrix while I need the second column

Can you share the URL of the page if it is public? If not, share the entire HTML in the question including all columns of the matrix.

there are too many characthers so I can't upload the entire html (but I can share a part of it)  and the page is not public unfortunatelly.

Iì've modified your code like this and it does what I was looking for: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='grid-content']//div[@role='row']//input)[4]").send_keys("100")
so thanks a lot, you drive me in the right direction!
